# mule message gathering exceptions

Tags: exception, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm thinking on one problem. If I have simple application which t.ex. send files from one place to another (SFTP) and this sftp connection is broken i catched possible exceptions. If there were t.ex 20 files. Exception strategy would send 20 emails for each try to send file. If there'll be thousands of files?? Is this possible to gather all this catched exceptions to one mail??

I did non-perfect solution - Exception strategy makes file with exceptions and next this file is consumed in next flow which send "error mail". I think it's not perfect. Do you have better solutions??

I'v seen 
https://www.appnovation.com/blog/handling-multiple-errors-mule-collection-aggregator
But it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to encapsulate the "send mail" component in a Cache scope that  expires in ,lets say, each 10 min, and that way you could limit the number of  emails that you receive?

Comment: Good, let me know if it meets your expectations.